# How to add an application to Azure AD with SSO option SAML

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I have created an application within the `Enterprise applications` tab and I don't have an option to `Setup Single Sign-On`. How can I add the SAML Sigle Sign-On option to my custom application? thanks.

**expected getting started options:**
[image]

**actual getting started options:**
[image]

Also the `Single sign-on` tab under the `Manage` options shows me the message like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message in the 3rd screenshot has told you about the reason.

Your **SampleWebApp** was created using the App registration experience. This kind of enterprise application doesn't support to configure SSO.

Only those created directly in Enterprise application experience can be configured SSO.

See the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso#prerequisites) here.

In [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal), you can learn how to add an app to your Azure AD tenant.

You can find this content:
[image]

Comment: Ok, got it. I will check out the prerequisite, but the second link is broken. I understand what the message says to me, but I added the app under the `Enterprise applications` tab.

Comment: So, the add app link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal from the Prerequisites page helped me to find out how to properly add an application, thanks.

Comment: @ЯрославТерещук Oh sorry. I put a bad link. I'll update my answer.